# jQuery ajax() function returning weird response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call with the jQuery `ajax()` function.
I keep getting the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <

Here is my function:

```
function testAjax(subject)
{    
$.ajax({
        url: '/profile/testAjax',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { field1: subject} ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        //your success code
        alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error: " + thrownError);
     }
    }); 
}
```

in my controller the `testAjax` function is as follows:

```
public function testAjax($subject)
{
    return "This works:" . $subject;
}
```

The function is called here:

```
$(document).on('click', '#applyButton', function(e) 
{
e.preventDefault();
testAjax($(this).val()) 
});
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this? I know it probably has something to do with the `contentType` and `dataType`.

**EDIT**

As the comments suggested, have looked at the HTTP response in Firebug:

```
GET write

200 OK

localhost

11.0 KB

127.0.0.1:80


83ms
GET jquery.min.js

200 OK

localhost

147 B

127.0.0.1:80


80ms
GET icons.woff2

200 OK

localhost

147 B

127.0.0.1:80


78ms
GET ajax?field1=Boogie

200 OK

localhost

3.1 KB

127.0.0.1:80


84ms
ParamsHeadersResponseHTMLCacheCookies

<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Missing argument 1 for profileController::ajax(), called in C:\wamp\www\application\router.class.php on line 85 and defined in C:\wamp\www\controller\profileController.php on line <i>440</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>254992</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0735</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2684528</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>router->loader(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>34</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0755</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2766056</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>profileController->ajax(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\application\router.class.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\router.class.php<b>:</b>85</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: subject in C:\wamp\www\controller\profileController.php on line <i>442</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>254992</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0735</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2684528</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>router->loader(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>34</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0755</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2766056</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>profileController->ajax(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\application\router.class.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\router.class.php<b>:</b>85</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: That error is showing you that you have a syntax error. It's not an AJAX response, at some point of your code, you have some problems. If you can create a JSFiddle, we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: Open the browser developer tools and look at the body of the HTTP response. You've told jQuery to expect JSON, but it's not JSON.

Comment: Also note that `contentType` is for the MIME type of the **request**, while `dataType` tells jQuery what you expect the **response** to look like. Thus you're setting up your HTTP request in a way that tells the *server* that you're sending JSON, but you're not really doing that.

Comment: OK, well that doesn't look like JSON, does it?  It's an error message telling you that there's a bug in your server-side code.

Comment: What `php` framework are you using?

Comment: @Victory I am using PHPPRO-MVC - http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

Comment: @Pointy If I supply a parameter to the url like this `url: '/profile/testAjax("Boogie")',` the error no longer appears but now it returns the entire HTML code from the page. Why is it doing that? I requested a method in the controller

Comment: I don't have any idea. I don't know how your server-side code works.